# Error while uploading apk built on Ionic to the google playstore

Tags: ionic-framework, google-play, apk

I find the following error while trying to upload my zip aligned apk onto the google play store.

**You need to use a different package name because "io.ionic.starter" already exists in Google Play.**

This is my first time uploading an application built on ionic to the playstore.

Comment: Have you tried changing the package name?

Answer (score 10):

Google play store already having app published with bundle `io.ionic.starter`

you can go to your config.xml and change your bundle id like:

```
<widget id="com.test.myapp" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
```

here `com.test.myapp` is your app's bundle id. than rebuild `release signed apk` and `zipalign`. and try to upload again.

Comment: is `config.xml` located at `app/res/xml`? This is the only `config.xml` file I can find in my project!

Comment: what is `zipalign`? I am using capacitor. Although I modified `app/res/xml/config.xml` file, I still get the same error when I try to deploy my app to google play!!

Answer (score 2):

That refers to the Bundle ID. Basically, it's a universally unique identifier for your app. Change the `id` property on line 2 of config.xml to a new Bundle ID. You can use this as a guide (it says iOS, but the same principle applies to Android): https://pspdfkit.com/guides/ios/current/faq/what-is-a-bundle-id/