# Ionic 4: You need to use a different package name because "io.ionic.starter" already exists in Google Play

Tags: android, android-studio, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am trying to deploy my ionic app to Google Play. However, when I upload the app apk file, I get this error message `You need to use a different package name because "io.ionic.starter" already exists in Google Play.` According to this thread: [Error while uploading apk built on Ionic to the google playstore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45046983/error-while-uploading-apk-built-on-ionic-to-the-google-playstore) I need to change my `config.xml` file, I only see config file in the path `app/res/xml/config.xml` which has this

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
  <access origin="*" />

</widget>
```

How do I solve this issue?
note that I have this in `capacitor.config.json`

```
{
  "appId": "io.ionic.stackie",
  "appName": "Stackie",
  "bundledWebRuntime": false,
  "npmClient": "npm",
  "webDir": "www",
  "cordova": {}
}
```

Answer (score 7):

If you updated the appId in the `capacitor.config.json` file after adding the android project with `npx cap add android`, the appId will not copy/update over to your android project.

Take a look at the `build.gradle` file in android->app folder and double-check that the applicationId is not `"io.ionic.starter"`. The `build.gradle` will probably look something like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myexampleapp.unique"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

 ...
```

If you update the applicationId in the `build.gradle` file and rebuild the project in Android Studio I think you will be good to go.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yep this worked for me. It looks like once you generate your android app from ionic this value stays set even if you rebuild with capacitor or cordova. I believe you would have to remove and then re-add android to fix all occurrences of the io.ionic.starter references but this is a great starting solution to keep making progress.

Answer (score 3):

I fixed this problem by replacing all occurrences of `io.ionic.starter` by `io.ionic.stackie` in `/android` directory. This might not be the best way to solve this issue but it worked with me.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this issue the following way (macOS Monterey):

In Android Studio, go to File > Project Structure. There you can change the Application ID.

Of course you need to rebuild your project:
Build > Generate Signed Bundle / APK…

If this does not work, read on for all of the steps I did before, even though I think that they could be skipped.

first in Android Studio I replaced all occurrences of "io.ionic.starter" by going to Edit > Find > Replace in Files …

Then in Android Studio I searched for files with 'config' in them and looked for "io.ionic.starter" and replaced it there manually. Even though the first step should have replaced it, it still was there.

As all of this did not help, I got inspired by @x7R5fQ and did a double click on the android folder in the Project tab of Android Studio.
Suddenly a Window called 'Project Structure' opened and I was able to change the Application ID there.

Answer (score -1):

not this config file. there is another config file is located in project root folder.you have to change the id. [image: root folder]

```
<widget id="io.ionic.starter">
```

Comment: I don't have it in my project, should I create one?